# Counter don't stop, SetInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this counter with setInterval which stops when more than a certain number .

The problem is that does not stop ?

Any ideas ?

Thank you

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {


    var myVar = setInterval(crecer, 1);

    function crecer(){

        var y = 0;

        console.log(y);
        y++;

        if (parseInt(y) > 100){
            myStopFunction();
        }   
    }

    function myStopFunction() {
        clearInterval(myVar);
        console.log("entro");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On each interval you're setting `y` to 0 again

Move y to be outside of the function block

```
var y = 0;
function crecer(){

    console.log(y);
    y++;

    if (parseInt(y) > 100){
        myStopFunction();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Beat me to the answer - here's a working jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e8a7264n/

Answer (score 0):

Each time you are calling your 'crecer' function after interval of 1ms, you are working in a new scope. Javascript has functional scoping for 'var' declaration. Try declaring 'y' outside function 'crecer'.